# Replacing duplicate items in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I stored a variable i exploded into an array into a session.

```
$totalSlip = explode(',',$_SESSION['isSlip']);
```

this gives me an array of

```
  Array ( 
    [0] => 25$$A 
    [1] => 34$$D 
    [2] => 32$$D 
  )
```

There are 3 values that are possible e.g 25$$A, 25$$D and 25$$H. My challenge is i want the a new value to substitute the value of a key in the array when it occurs more than once. e.g if 25$$A already exist and i add 25$$D what it gives me is

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 25$$A 
    [1] => 34$$D 
    [2] => 32$$D 
    [3] => 25$$D
  )
```

but what i want is this

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 25$$D
    [1] => 34$$D 
    [2] => 32$$D
  )
```

i want the value of array[0] to be replaced. 
I'll appreciate any help i can get, thanks.

Comment: Also, why are you using string concatenation then exploding it later? You can store arrays in PHP sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, you need to change your logic to use the arrays this way. Have the integer to be the array key and the character, to be the value. So, your array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 25$$A 
    [1] => 34$$D 
    [2] => 32$$D 
)
```

Should look something like this:

```
Array (
    [25] => A 
    [34] => D 
    [32] => D 
)
```

This way, you can just make changes to the logic by updating the key with this:

```
$array[25] = "D";
```

And this makes the below if the array key exists:

```
Array (
    [25] => D 
    [34] => D 
    [32] => D 
)
```

Or if it doesn't exist, it creates one! For eg:

```
$array[65] = "A";

Array (
    [25] => A 
    [34] => D 
    [32] => D 
    [65] => A 
)
```